# Access Query IIf Value in Values returned by another Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a Query that looks up an Employee ID, Employee Name and Team Name from the current Staff Database. I have another Query that lists all unique values in Team Name. (Team Name is an Integer, and corresponds to Employee ID, also an Integer.)

Eg this is how teams are structured. Emp ID 100 belongs to Emp ID 10's team. 10 belongs to 5. 5 belongs to 1, etc.

EmpID = 100
TeamName = 10

EmpID = 10
TeamName = 5

EmpID = 5
TeamName = 1

What I am trying to do is return a fourth field, giving an asterisk, "*", when the Emp ID also appears in the Team Name query (Thus meaning they have a team/are a Manager).

I have a DCount that works, but it is slower than I'd like, and will only get slower as the Database grows, but it might serve to explain what I need.

Expr1: IIf(DCount("TeamName","jdbo_MostRecentEmpDataRemain","TeamName = " & [EmpID])>0,"*","")

jdbo_MostRecentEmpDataRemain is a Query that returns all data for staff that are active.

This will return an Asterisk if the EmpID has team members assigned to them, and nothing if they do not.

I'm wondering if this can be applied through queries to make it faster. Please let me know if you have any suggesstions.

I tried this: Expr2: IIf([EmpID] In ([qryListOfTeams].[TeamName]),"a","z")
but that returns lots of z's and then an a, as it seems to return a value for every value that is in the Team List. I want it to aggregate those and display an a if there is an a, otherwise a z. (Where in the original "*" is the a, and "" is the z)

Kind regards,

Jamie Warburton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
 SELECT * FROM TableOrQuery
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EmpID FROM Teams 
            WHERE EmpID In (SELECT TeamName FROM Teams)) As a
 ON TableOrQuery.EmpID =  a.EmpID
```

Derived tables are usually faster than subqueries.

EDIT re comment

Asterisk has a specific meaning, so while you can do this, I do not recommend it.

```
 SELECT TableOrQuery.*, a.IsTeam FROM TableOrQuery
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, "*" As IsTeam FROM Teams 
            WHERE EmpID In (SELECT TeamName FROM Teams)) As a
 ON TableOrQuery.EmpID =  a.EmpID
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. This seems to list the EmpID of the employee again, but only if they have a team, so it's on the right track. Is there a way to, instead of showing the EmpID, just show an Asterisk?

Comment: Yes, but asterisks have a specific meaning in SQL, so I would make it a display matter for your form or report. I will add a note, but with a caution.

Comment: Well I suppose it doesn't necessarily need to be an asterisk. A simple "x" would do. There's 4 list boxes, the first displays the current employee's team. If you click a name, it shows their team in the next list box, and so on (teams only have a maximum order of 4, hence 4 boxes). The Asterisk would be displayed after the name if they had a team, so it doesn't really matter what character it is